# Logistic function misclassification

Tags: python, numpy, activation-function

I'm having trouble trying to teach a neural network the XOR logic function. I've already trained the network with succesful results using the hyperbolic tangent and ReLU as activation functions (regarding the ReLU, I know it's not the appropiate for this kind of problem, but I still wanted to test it). Still, I can't make it work with the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). My definition of the function is:

```
def logistic(data):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-data))
```

and its derivative:

```
def logistic_prime(data):
    output = logistic(data)
    return output * (1.0 - output)
```

where `np` is the name given to the **NumPy** imported package. As the XOR logic uses are 0's and 1's, the logistic function should be an appropriate activation function. Still, the results I get are close to 0.5 in all cases, i.e. any input combination of 0's and 1's results in a value close to 0.5. Is there any error in what I'm saying?

Don't hesitate in asking me for more context or more code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could assign the output of `logistic(data)` to a local variable in `logistic_prime` and use it twice, rather than actually calling the function twice.  That's nothing to do with your problem, but at least training would fail faster.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you.
The problem happens when the data can not the divided by a linear hyperplane.
Try to train the data:

```
X = [[-1,0],[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1]]
Y = [1,0,1,0]
```

if you draw this down on a coordinate, then you will fine it is not linearly dividable.
Train it on logistic, parameters are all close to 0 and result close to 0.5.

Another linearly dividable example is use `Y = [1,1,0,0]`
and logistic work.